# How to change real screen timeout settings for the Lock Screen?

Tags: windows-10, power-management

I have my PC connected to a TV, because it's significantly cheaper than the same screen with "computer display" label.

To make us regret for the money saved, manufacturers of both types of devices ensured, that TVs should not turn off when no input signal. They use to display very bright, ugly and annoying screen "no signal" and eventually, they would turn off after minimum of 15 or 30 minutes.

However, Windows 10 lock screen turns the screen off like in a minute. Then it requires one click to "wake up", another click to activate pin or password input. It looks bad, it's annoying. BTW, what's the point in choosing lock screen background picture if it's hardly shown?

So I'm looking for the way to change power management settings for the lock screen. It's different form user settings.

It is NOT in Lock Screen Settings (where I would expect it). There is even an option "Screen timeout settings", but it is set to 1 hour. The screen is turned off after like 1 minute, not 1 hour, so it doesn't work. 1 hour is my user setting, it's works when I'm signed in to my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Source: [ON MSFT](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/adjust-windows-10-lock-screen-timeout).

- Here's the Registry key:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7`
- Set `Attributes` to `2`.
- Then enter the `Edit Plan Settings` window, find `Display` node, `Console lock display off timeout` property and set it to anything. Like `0` to turn the feature completely off.