# How to configure Windows to lock screen on sleep/wake but not on display-off

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

This relates to Windows 10 Pro version 1903.

The ideal behavior I want is for my laptop to:

- turn off the display after a few minutes of inactivity
- go to sleep if inactive for a longer period (an hour)
- if it is in a "display off" state (not yet sleeping), I want it to resume without the lock screen
- if it has gone to sleep (either by extended inactivity or commanded by the power button) that it will wake to the lock screen.

I haven't found the combination of settings to achieve this; from all the combinations I have tried (including group policy settings), lock screen seems to be all or nothing; if it wakes from sleep to the lock screen then it will also go to the lock screen when it resumes from a "display off" state; if it resumes from "display off" without the lock screen, then it will also wake without the lock screen.

Is there a combination of settings I am overlooking to achieve the behavior I want? Does Windows 10 1903 even allow for it?

**EDIT:**

I tried to follow [this answer to my question](https://superuser.com/a/1459468/254296), but found that my system does not offer the "System unattended sleep" option... is there a group policy option or registry setting I need to set/modify to enable it?

[image]

Comment: Did you perform the necessary registry edit to enable the option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change real screen timeout settings for the Lock Screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1414230/how-to-change-real-screen-timeout-settings-for-the-lock-screen)

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

- In *Start > Change screen saver*, set the screen saver to "None"
- In *Start > Power Options > Change plan settings*, set

  - *Turn off the display* to, say, "5 minutes"
  - *Put the computer to sleep* to "1 hour"
- Start *Task Scheduler* and create a new task, as follows:

  - *General*: Give it a name; check "Run only when user is logged on"
  - *Trigger*: "On an event"; Custom; New Event Filter, defined as *Level*: Information;
    *Source*: Power-Troubleshooter; *Event id*:1
  - Action: Start a program; Program: `rundll32.exe`; Arguments: `user32.dll,LockWorkStation`

Answer (score 1):

Enabling and setting System Unattended Sleep Timeout to match your desired sleep timeout should allow Display off to function as you desire.
[(see first answer)](https://superuser.com/questions/1019043/windows-10-sleeps-before-set-time)
To enable, edit the **Attributes** value under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0**
[image: Regedit]

Then, Advanced Power Options will show:
[image]

Comment: Seems my advanced power options don't match yours; I don't have a "System unattended sleep timeout"

Comment: You have to add it through a Registry edit. That's in the link.

Comment: System unattended sleep timeout power setting is the idle timeout before the system returns to a low power sleep state after waking unattended. What's the connection here?

Comment: Despite it official description, its default value of 2 minutes seems to be what triggers "premature" sleep.